# Why does kubectl exec need a --?

Tags: kubernetes

If I run the command

```
$ kubectl exec pod-name echo Hello World
```

I get a deprecation error message asking me to include the '--' characters.

```
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
```

Why was the decision made to require the '--' characters there? It seems unnecessary to me. I understand it's deprecated, I'm just trying to understand the reasoning behind the decision.

Comment: `--` is a shell thing.  It is a way in shell(not just limited to kubectl),  to tell the command(kubectl) to consider anything after -- as argument not the flags.

Comment: Eg `grep -E` vs `grep -- -E`

Comment: In the 2nd grep, `-E` is considered as string ,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According the book "Kubernetes in action" by Marko Luksa:

> Why the double dash?

> The double dash (--) in the command signals the end of command options for
> kubectl. Everything after the double dash is the command that should be executed
> inside the pod . Using the double dash isn’t necessary if the command has no
> arguments that start with a dash. But in your case, if you don’t use the double dash
> there, the -s option would be interpreted as an option for kubectl exec and would
> result in the following strange and highly misleading error:
> $ kubectl exec kubia-7nog1 curl -s http://10.111.249.153
> The connection to the server 10.111.249.153 was refused – did you
> specify the right host or port?
> This has nothing to do with your service refusing the connection. It’s because
> kubectl is not able to connect to an API server at 10.111.249.153 (the -s option
> is used to tell kubectl to connect to a different API server than the default).